# How to use asp.net button/link trigger function and pass variable, not using gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, variables, webforms

I'm created a table with a delete button for every row, on a web form, and I'm having trouble getting the delete button to work.  The web form code is:

```
<% foreach (var item in itemList)
    { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= item.Title %></td>
        <td><%= item.Description %></td>
        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnCommand="btnDelete_Click" CommandArgument="<%= item.ItemId %>" /></td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
```

And the code behind:

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
        string itemId = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        if (itemId != null)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the variable "itemId" doesn't actually contain the id of the item.  It just has "<%= item.ItemId %>" as a string.  Is there any way of creating a table with a delete button/link on each row that will send the id of that item to the code behind function so I can delete that item?  I have a feeling gridview will do it, but I don't want to use gridview.

Comment: `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("item.ItemId")%>'`

Comment: Didn't work.  itemId = ""